# Get images from google drive API

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, api, google-drive-api

I am using node.js to try and get the images out of my google drive. I’ve finished the the getting started and tried to use download to put it in a file. My code is showing that I successfully downloaded it but I can’t see the image the file. I’m fairly new to API’s. I just want to get my image and be able to render it to my page to be viewed. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require ("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



// Google getting started section
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
                               'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles,downloadFile);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

  drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {

      console.log('Files:');
      files.map((file) => {

        downloadFile(auth);

      });
    } else {
      console.log('No files found.');
    }
  });
}

// download to local file  
function downloadFile(auth) {const drive = google.drive({version: "v3", 
  auth});
 var fileId = "######";

 var dest = fs.createWriteStream("public/images/photo.jpg");

 drive.files.get({fileId: fileId, alt: "media"}, {responseType: "stream"},
 function(err, res){
    res.data
    .on("end", () => {

    })
    .on("error", err => {
       console.log("Error", err);
    })
    .pipe(dest);

// I am geeting success but I cant find the Image
    console.log("success");
 });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your current script for replicating your issue? If you can do, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will solve the issue, but my guess is that the problem is the `path` where to write the file to. The code itself seems to come straight from [the API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads), and seems to be correct.

Based on [the official documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths), relative paths start with a slash (`/`).

So try changing this:

```js
var dest = fs.createWriteStream("public/images/photo.jpg");
```

With this:

```js
var dest = fs.createWriteStream("/public/images/photo.jpg");
```

#### Reference:

- [Node.js: File System > File paths](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html)

Comment: I tried doing this and I got the following error                                                                     
        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:/public/images/photo.jpg'
        Emitted 'error' event at:
        at lazyFs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:277:12)
        at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)

Comment: Is there a way to pull the data from google API and just render it to the page without having to store it on the server before hand?

Comment: @JoshAllred That means the path `/public/images/photo.jpg` is not in the application's directory. Do you know where it is? Regarding your second question, you should be able to do it, but whether it is desirable or not and which way you should follow depends on the specific situation you are in. You could, for example, have your images in a public folder and just render the image using the corresponding URL, or you could just send the retrieved image from the API as a response, without using `fs.createWriteStream`.

Comment: I have it set up using express. I Have a public folder has a js folder that has a index.js in it the public folder also contains a css folder that has my styles.css in it and also a images folder with a image file in it. Js and css are both working correctly.

Comment: @JoshAllred So, if you're executing this from `index.js`, and you're trying to access a different subdirectory, I think this should work: `fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/../css/images/photo.jpg");`. Tell me if it does and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I got it to work I names the file wrong. If I were to send the image as a response how do I do that? I can't figure out how to decode it.

Comment: @JoshAllred I guess something like `res.sendFile(imagePath)` would work. In any case, I'd recommend you to create a new question for this.